# How to calculate length and width of point list

Tags: algorithm, math, 3d

I have a list of point (3d space) that can seem randomly disposed, what I need is to get the size of the smallest box that will fit the point group. I hope I'm clear.

Thanks

Comment: For the purpose of trading off algorithm running time versus complexity of implementation, how many points are there?

Comment: Wikipedia has a description of O'Rourke's cubic-time algorithm, which is the fastest known: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_bounding_box_algorithms

Comment: A small number of point, and speed is not the main thing, say 10 to 100. I will check wikipedia, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it seemed hard for me to apply the algorithm explained on wikipedia I used a technique based on the fact I don't need the optimal bounding box but a near one.
I do that in 3 steps:

-first I use a angle which go from 0 to pi and convert it to a vector (cos(a),sin(a),0), then I project each point on it using the dot product which gives me a maximum and a minimum (a length), I keep the vector that has the longest length.

-next I create a coordinate system with from this vector, axe0: the vector, axe1: (0,0,1) and axe2, the cross product of the 2 others. and I do the same as the first step: an angle, gives a vector but this time the vector is converted to the new coordinate system using dot products, and again I find the best angle (the best vector)

-and finally I have the utlimate best vector which will become the length direction, the third direction will be the cross product of the last one and the one found on first step, and the second one will be the cross of the 2. I then just have to project all the points to the 3 axes to have the box dimensions

That works !